# Protecting my digital art when turning it into NFT

Tags: nft

I have a collection of several pics that I want to turn into NFT. What I am worried about is that someone can save my NFT as a file, and then make a new NFT out of it and sell it in several copies. Is that a real danger, and how can one protect from it?

Comment: I've added one last thing to my answer at the very end. This may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about this being a "real danger". This is completely possible and there is almost nothing you can do to prevent this. I am not an expert but the main thing you can do is "advertisement". You use the power of everything to publicly announce that "you are actually creating some piece of art and selling it as NFT" and then you point to your NFT collection in a marketplace (Opensea, rarible, etc).

Some marketplaces (like [Superrare](https://superrare.com/)) verify the artists and only sell items from verified artists. This ensures that the buyer is actually buying a valuable piece of art and not a scam. But still: there is nothing prevent someone to download your image and try to sell it on Opensea. Would someone buy the scammer's NFT? I doubt... But what if he/she makes more advertisements?

**Update**: I forgot to mention about the "verified account/collection" of Opensea. "Sane" buyers would try to buy NFTs that are verified. Read more about [here](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063519133-What-is-a-verified-account-or-collection-).

Comment: Thanks. Essentially you mean that unless I warmed up the public, someone can "remint" my art at some other market place and have a higher success of selling it than me? So my goal should be that my account should seem a kinda stronger legit reason to by the same stuff from me, than the same pic from someone else.

Comment: Sadly, exactly... @Ilya

Comment: @Ilya even when you are "warming up" the public, people may use your reputation to create scam arts and websites. I believe you need to make a fast and very strong advertisement and direct people to the correct (your) NFT collection. I know this is a bt scary but you are an artist. You have the strength and will to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the words of support! What about the copyright laws, can they be of any help?

Comment: @Ilya Could be... You can file lawsuits against scammer websites or social platform profiles owned by scammers. People can still mint your art as NFT and you (or authorities) may not be able to track down the scammer minters from their wallet addresses  BUT I don't think they can be successful without any advertisement.